# Is $\left|\frac{\det(A_{\mu\nu})}{\det(B_{\mu\nu})}\right|$ an invariant for two tensors $A_{\mu\nu}$ and $B_{\mu\nu}$ in a manifold?

Tags: manifolds, tensor-calculus

I was doing some math around the determinant of 2nd-order covariant tensors. In a general $n$-dimensional manifold, I deduced that the determinant of a tensor $A_{\mu\nu}$ can be defined as
$$
\det(A_{\mu\nu})=\tilde\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n}\tilde\epsilon^{\nu_1\cdots \nu_n}A_{\mu_1\nu_1}\cdots A_{\mu_n\nu_n},
$$
based on a generalization of 2-dimensional tensor determinants, where $\tilde\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol with $\tilde\epsilon^{1\cdots n}=1$ for a general metric.

Using the definition of the Levi-Civita symbol, I proved that the Levi-Civita **tensor**, if being antisymmetric w.r.t. any pair of its superscripts, must have the following form:
$$
\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n}=s\cdot \tilde\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n},
$$
where $\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n}$ is the Levi-Civita tensor and $s$ is a (non-invariant) scalar. Using the tensor transformation law and assuming $s$ to be non-negative, I deduced that a sufficient condition for $\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n}$ to be a tensor, is to have $s=I\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\det(A_{\mu\nu})|}}$ for an arbitrary non-singular tensor $A_{\mu\nu}$ and arbitrary non-negative invariant $I$. My question originates from here.

> If both $I\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\det(A_{\mu\nu})|}}\tilde\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n}$ and $J\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\det(B_{\mu\nu})|}}\tilde\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n}$ are tensors for arbitrary non-negative invariants $I$ and $J$ and non-singular tensors $A_{\mu\nu}$ and $B_{\mu\nu}$, does it mean that $\frac{|\det(A_{\mu\nu})|}{|\det(B_{\mu\nu})|}$ is an invariant? If not, where did I go wrong?

**Edit**

Here is my proof attempt (the tensor transformation law happens between two coordinates systems, $x^\mu$ and $\hat x^\mu$; a tensor $T$ in $x^\mu$-system has an equivalent for of $\hat T$ in $\hat x^\mu$-system):

$$
{\hat\epsilon^{\hat\mu_1\cdots\hat\mu_n}=\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n}
\frac{\partial \hat x^{\hat\mu_1}}{\partial x^{\mu_1}}\cdots\frac{\partial \hat x^{\hat\mu_n}}{\partial x^{\mu_n}}
\\\implies
\hat s\cdot \hat{\tilde\epsilon}^{\hat\mu_1\cdots\hat\mu_n}
=
s\cdot \tilde\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n}
\frac{\partial \hat x^{\hat\mu_1}}{\partial x^{\mu_1}}\cdots\frac{\partial \hat x^{\hat\mu_n}}{\partial x^{\mu_n}}.
}
$$
If we apply $\hat\epsilon^{\hat\nu_1\cdots\hat\nu_n}\hat T_{\hat \mu_1\hat\nu_1}\cdots \hat T_{\hat \mu_n\hat\nu_n}$ to the both sides of the latter, we obtain
$$
{
\hat s\cdot\hat{\tilde\epsilon}^{\hat\mu_1\cdots\hat\mu_n}
\hat\epsilon^{\hat\nu_1\cdots\hat\nu_n}\hat T_{\hat \mu_1\hat\nu_1}\cdots\hat T_{\hat \mu_n\hat\nu_n}
=
s\cdot\tilde\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n}
\hat\epsilon^{\hat\nu_1\cdots\hat\nu_n}\hat T_{\hat \mu_1\hat\nu_1}\cdots \hat T_{\hat \mu_n\hat\nu_n}
\frac{\partial \hat x^{\hat\mu_1}}{\partial x^{\mu_1}}\cdots\frac{\partial \hat x^{\hat\mu_n}}{\partial x^{\mu_n}}
\\\implies
|\hat s|^2\cdot\det(\hat T)
=
|s|^2\cdot\tilde\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n}
\tilde\epsilon^{\hat\nu_1\cdots\hat\nu_n}
\frac{\partial \hat x^{\hat\nu_1}}{\partial x^{\nu_1}}\cdots\frac{\partial \hat x^{\hat\nu_n}}{\partial x^{\nu_n}}
\hat T_{\hat \mu_1\hat\nu_1}\cdots \hat T_{\hat \mu_n\hat\nu_n}
\frac{\partial \hat x^{\hat\mu_1}}{\partial x^{\mu_1}}\cdots\frac{\partial \hat x^{\hat\mu_n}}{\partial x^{\mu_n}}
\\\implies
|\hat s|^2\cdot\det(\hat T)
=
|s|^2\cdot\tilde\epsilon^{\mu_1\cdots \mu_n}
\tilde\epsilon^{\hat\nu_1\cdots\hat\nu_n}
T_{ \mu_1\nu_1}\cdots T_{\mu_n\nu_n}
\\\implies
|\hat s|^2\cdot\det(\hat T)=|s|^2\cdot\det(T),
}
$$
from which, I deduced that $|s|^2\cdot\det(T)$ must be an invariant, and so forth.